# SFTP Manual command succeed but script is failing at 1 or 2%

Tags: linux, sftp, expect, nas, synology

I wrote a script to transfer a folder from VPS to Synology NAS Server. The script fails at 1 or 2% transfer without any indication why. When I run the command manually it works fine without any issues and it transfer the folder flawlessly. I'm not sure what is causing this and would appreciate if i can get some guidance on where to look.

SCRIPT:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set dir [timestamp -format "%Y-%m-%d"]
spawn sftp user@host.mybackup.me
expect "Password:"
send "passw0rd\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd /directory/\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "put -r /home/backup/$dir\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "bye\n"
```

RESULT:

```
root@host [/scripts]# ./sftp.sh
spawn sftp user@host.synology.me
user@host.mybackup.me's password:
Connected to host.mybackup.me
sftp> cd /directory/for/backup
sftp> put -r /home/backup/2017-12-26
Uploading /home/backup/2017-12-26/ to /backup/2017-12-26
Entering /home/backup/2017-12-26/
Entering /home/backup/2017-12-26/accounts
/home/backup/2017-12-26/file1.tar.gz       2%   26MB   1.8MB/s   08:41 ETAroot@host [/scripts]#
root@host [/scripts]#
```

MANUAL COMMAND:

```
root@host [/scripts]# sftp user@host.synology.me
backup@host.mybackup.me's password:
Connected to host.mybackup.me.
sftp> cd directory
sftp> put -r /home/backup/2017-12-26
Uploading /home/backup/2017-12-26/ to /backups/2017-12-26
Entering /home/backup/2017-12-26/
Entering /home/backup/2017-12-26/accounts
/home/backup/2017-12-26/file.tar.gz             100%  959MB 820.2KB/s   19:57
/home/backup/2017-12-26/file2.tar.gz            100%  147MB   1.4MB/s   01:45
sftp> bye
root@host [/Scripts]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, in your case, timeout happened with respect to `Expect`, since the file transfer takes some extra time than the default timeout (10seconds). You can either set the `timeout` to -1 or you can increase it to some higher value and the they are in the units of seconds.

```
set timeout -1; # Infinite amount of waiting time
```

or

```
set timeout 300; # 5 minutes of waiting time
```

You can keep the above statement in your code.

```
send "put -r /home/backup/$dir\n"
expect {
    timeout {puts "timeout happened"}
    "sftp>"
}
send "bye\r"
expect eof
```

Always use `\r` character to send 'Enter' key instead of `\n`. The last statement `expect eof` will wait for the graceful closure of `sftp` program.

Comment: @EmilyE. : `\n` will still work, but that `\n` will be converted to `\r` internally.

Comment: Actually `\r` is usually converted to `\n` on input, not `\n` -> `\r`.